# Default ATI Path Change setting on Samsung Galaxy A20

Tags: settings, dialer-codes, samsung-galaxy-a20

I've just purchased my Samsung Galaxy A20 and was configuring my settings, and I'm unsure what this specific setting does.

```
ATI Path Change (Both)
[0] Physical UART path
[1] AP path
[2] Both ATI, No RmPC
```

I accidentally hit my screen and it chose an option. Now I'm unsure what the default setting was.

I've tried to look it up but no luck to help guide me on the right or default setting was.

I've chosen "Both ATI, No RmPC", but which one was the default setting?

Answer (score 1):

The default is:

(2) Both ATI, No RmPC